# Disable Quick Edit PowerShell/cmd prompt

Tags: regedit, ansible

I've tried to disable quickedit through regedit : `HKCU:\Console QuickEdit = "0"` ; the value changes in the registry but nothing happens.

I know I can right-click edit properties but I need to find the right registry so I can automate it through ansible.

Comment: Did you restart the pc after the registry change?